# iOS AudioConverter exceeds maximum packet size (2048) for input format

Tags: ios, aac, audiotoolbox, audio-converter

I'm trying to decode aac to pcm data, my goal is to decode the acc data received by tcp into pcm data. Currently I want to convert local aac files to pcm data first, and I encounter a problem:

```
[AudioConverter] CompositeAudioConverter.cpp:1063 Packet description 0 of 1 (size 1009664) exceeds maximum packet size (2048) for input format
```

I first convert all the aac files to data, and then directly feed it to the decoder, and get the above error.

Below is my decoder code：

```
- (void)setupDecoder{
    AudioStreamBasicDescription outputAudioDes;
    memset(&outputAudioDes, 0, sizeof(outputAudioDes));
    
    outputAudioDes.mSampleRate = (Float64)_config.sampleRate;    outputAudioDes.mChannelsPerFrame = (UInt32)_config.channelCount;
    outputAudioDes.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM; 
    outputAudioDes.mFormatFlags = (kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked);
    outputAudioDes.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    outputAudioDes.mBitsPerChannel = 16; 
    outputAudioDes.mBytesPerFrame = outputAudioDes.mBitsPerChannel / 8 * outputAudioDes.mChannelsPerFrame;
    outputAudioDes.mBytesPerPacket = outputAudioDes.mBytesPerFrame * outputAudioDes.mFramesPerPacket;
    outputAudioDes.mReserved = 0;
    
    
    AudioStreamBasicDescription inputAudioDes;
    memset(&inputAudioDes, 0, sizeof(inputAudioDes));
    
    inputAudioDes.mSampleRate = (Float64)_config.sampleRate;
    inputAudioDes.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    inputAudioDes.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_LC;
    inputAudioDes.mFramesPerPacket = 1024;
    inputAudioDes.mChannelsPerFrame = (UInt32)_config.channelCount;
    
    
    UInt32 inDesSize = sizeof(inputAudioDes);
    AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL, &inDesSize, &inputAudioDes);
    
    
    AudioClassDescription *audioClassDesc = [self getAudioClassDescriptionWithType:outputAudioDes.mFormatID fromManufacture:kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer];
    
   
    OSStatus status = AudioConverterNewSpecific(&inputAudioDes,
                                                &outputAudioDes,
                                                1,
                                                audioClassDesc,
                                                &_audioConverter);
    if (status != noErr){
        NSLog(@"Error!: status = %d",(int)status);
        return;
    }
}

- (AudioClassDescription *)getAudioClassDescriptionWithType:(AudioFormatID)type fromManufacture:(uint32_t)manufacture{
    static AudioClassDescription desc;
    UInt32 decoderSpecific = type;
    
   
    UInt32 size;
    OSStatus status = AudioFormatGetPropertyInfo(kAudioFormatProperty_Decoders, sizeof(decoderSpecific), &decoderSpecific, &size);
    if (status != noErr){
        NSLog(@"Error!:  status = %d",(int)status);
        return nil;
    }
    
    unsigned int count = size / sizeof(AudioClassDescription);
    AudioClassDescription description[count];
    status = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_Encoders, sizeof(decoderSpecific), &decoderSpecific, &size, &description);
    if (status != noErr){
        NSLog(@"Error!: status = %d",(int)status);
        return nil;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (type == description[i].mSubType &&
            manufacture == description[i].mManufacturer){
            desc = description[i];
            return &desc;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)decodeAudioAACData:(NSData *)aacData{
    if (!_audioConverter){
        return;
    }
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(_decoderQueue, ^{
        SRAudioUserData userData = {0};
        userData.channelCount = (UInt32)weakSelf.config.channelCount;
        userData.data = (char *)[aacData bytes];
        userData.size = (UInt32)aacData.length;
        userData.packetDesc.mDataByteSize = (UInt32)aacData.length;
        userData.packetDesc.mStartOffset = 0;
        userData.packetDesc.mVariableFramesInPacket = 0;
        
     
        const uint32_t MAX_AUDIO_FRAMES = 2048;
        UInt32 pcmBufferSize = (UInt32)(MAX_AUDIO_FRAMES * self->_config.channelCount);
        UInt32 pcmDataPacketSize = 1;
        
       
        uint8_t *pcmBuffer = malloc(pcmBufferSize);
        memset(pcmBuffer, 0, pcmBufferSize);
        
        
        AudioBufferList outAudioBufferList = {0};
        outAudioBufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = (uint32_t)self->_config.channelCount;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)pcmBufferSize;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = pcmBuffer;
        
        
        AudioStreamPacketDescription outputPacketDesc;
        memset(&outputPacketDesc, 0, sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription));
        outputPacketDesc.mDataByteSize = MAX_AUDIO_FRAMES;
        outputPacketDesc.mStartOffset = 0;
        outputPacketDesc.mVariableFramesInPacket = 0;
        
        
        OSStatus status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(self->_audioConverter,
                                                          &AudioDecoderConverterComplexInputDataProc,
                                                          &userData,
                                                          &pcmDataPacketSize,
                                                          &outAudioBufferList,
                                                          &outputPacketDesc);
        if (status != noErr){
            NSLog(@"Error: AAC Decoder error, status = %d",(int)status);
            return;
        }
        
        if (outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize > 0){
            NSData *rawData = [NSData dataWithBytes:outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];
            NSLog(@"rawData %ld", rawData.length);
            dispatch_async(weakSelf.callbackQueue, ^{
                [weakSelf.delegate audioDecoderCallback:rawData];
            });
        }
        free(pcmBuffer);
    });
}

- (void)dealloc{
    if (_audioConverter){
        AudioConverterDispose(_audioConverter);
        _audioConverter = NULL;
    }
}


static OSStatus AudioDecoderConverterComplexInputDataProc(AudioConverterRef inAudioConverter,
                                                          UInt32 *ioNumberDataPackets,
                                                          AudioBufferList *ioData,
                                                          AudioStreamPacketDescription **outDataPacketDescription,
                                                          void *inUserData){
    SRAudioUserData *audioDecoder = (SRAudioUserData *)(inUserData);
    if (audioDecoder->size <= 0){
        ioNumberDataPackets = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    if (outDataPacketDescription){
        *outDataPacketDescription = &audioDecoder->packetDesc;
        (*outDataPacketDescription)[0].mStartOffset = 0;
        (*outDataPacketDescription)[0].mDataByteSize = audioDecoder->size;
        (*outDataPacketDescription)[0].mVariableFramesInPacket = 0;
    }
    
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mData = audioDecoder->data;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = audioDecoder->size;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = audioDecoder->channelCount;
    
    return noErr;
}
```

Below are the default property values for my `_config`:

```
self.bitrate = 6400;
self.channelCount = 2;
self.sampleSize = 16;
self.sampleRate = 44100;
```

This is my code to convert aac file to data:

```swift
if let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hello.aac", ofType: nil),
   let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: audioPath){
   let audioDecoder = SRAudioDecoder(config: nil)
                            
   if let streamData = try? Data(reading: stream){
       audioDecoder.decodeAudioAACData(streamData)
   }
}

// Data Extension
init(reading input: InputStream) throws {
    self.init()
    input.open()
    defer {
        input.close()
    }

    let bufferSize = 1024
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
    defer {
        buffer.deallocate()
    }
    while input.hasBytesAvailable {
        let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
        if read < 0 {
            //Stream error occured
            throw input.streamError!
        } else if read == 0 {
            //EOF
            break
        }
        self.append(buffer, count: read)
    }
}
```

I try to split the data into 1024 for the decoder, but there is still an error:

```
Error: AAC Decoder error, status = 1650549857
AACDecoder.cpp:200    Unmatched number of channel elements in payload
AACDecoder.cpp:228    Error deserializing packet
ACMP4AACBaseDecoder.cpp:1438  (0x108811840) Error decoding packet 141: err = -1, packet length: 1024
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.